# Model Validation from Unit Testing only works for string

Tags: c#, validation, unit-testing

I have got a class like this

Model:

```
public class Circle
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Diameter is required")]
    public int Diameter { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is required")]
    public string Color { get; set; }
}
```

Testing:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestCircle()
{
    Circle circle = new Circle();
    circle.Diameter = 5;
    circle.Color = "Black";
    ValidationContext contex = new ValidationContext(circle, null, null);
    Validator.ValidateObject(circle , contex);
}
```

I was expecting it'd fail whenever Diameter or Color is null. However, the above testing only failed when the string parameter, Color, is null. Why? How should I do in order to validate Diameter as well?

Comment: I'd guess its because int is not nullable and will default to 0, therefore being valid in this context. Not entirely sure. What happens if you use ?int (nullable int) in your circle class?

Comment: `int` will be defaulted to 0, if you want to test `null` you have to use `int?`. Also I think you wanted to write `circle.Diameter` instead of `Circle.Diameter` because `Diameter` is not `static`

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use the [Required](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.requiredattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute with numeric  properties. Use the [Range](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.rangeattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute instead:

> The RequiredAttribute attribute specifies that when a field on a form
>   is validated, the field must contain a value. A validation exception
>   is raised if the property is null, contains an empty string (""), or
>   contains only white-space characters.

Answer (score 2):

RequiredAttribute only validates against null (and empty strings), but an int is non-nullable and becomes 0 by default.

You could make it nullable (with `int?`) or you could use a different kind of attribute. As DmitryG says, you could use the RangeAttribute if there's a certain range of numbers that are acceptable to you, but if not I think the only way would be a CustomValidationAttribute with a function to compare the value to zero.

EDIT: Given that it's a diameter, I guess you need to make sure it's positive, and not just unequal to zero. In this case a RangeAttribute may indeed be best, with 1 as the minimum and `Int32.MaxValue` as the maximum.